# Sending multiple async emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I want to send multiple emails asynchronously. Emails do not depend on each other and no code will run after emails send, so i want to fire multiple and forget. I am following [this article](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2) for sending async emails but i am not sure if i am doing the right thing for sending multiple emails.

A few of my concerns;

- Sending of second email should not wait for first one.
- Should i use QueueBackgroundWorkItem for each email sending task or use one QueueBackgroundWorkItem?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage
            ("abc@domain.com", message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);
        using(var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Action<CancellationToken> workItem = SendEmails;
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(workItem);

        return View();
    }

    private async void SendEmails(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await SendEmailAsync(new IdentityMessage(...));
        await SendEmailAsync(new IdentityMessage(...));
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `QueuebackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task>` for asynchronous methods and mark your `SendEmails` to return Task. Otherwise asp.net will assume that your method is completed at first await point itself, not when all await points are done

Comment: I think caller will wait for all awaits as each await in the method will wait for previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SendEmails every next email is waiting for completion of previous, you should rewrite it like this:

```
private async Task SendEmails(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        await Task.WhenAll(SendEmailAsync(new IdentityMessage(...)),
                           SendEmailAsync(new IdentityMessage(...)));
}
```

By doing so all email will be send in parallel.
Also you should not QueueBackgroundWorkItem in Create. You can just do next:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
 {
        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async (token)=> await SendEmails() );

        return View();
 }
```

But please keep in mind that if any exception occur in SendEmails you will not be notified about this. Let me know if this can be an issue for you, so i will provide solution for this.

But i prefer another approach of sending emails from web application. It is more complicated but more reliable. Web app should never send messages to smtp server but store request to queue or db. Than we have background application that listen to queue and every time new request was detected it try to send it to smtp. if attempt fail system will return request back to the queue and will try few more times later. This background app may be windows service of webjob if your app is hosted in azure. 
Advantages of this approach:

1. no UI thread blocking - to put something in queue is short running operation
2. even if smtp server is not accessible for some period of time you are sure that all emails will be delivered

Disadvantages:

1. You have to maintain additional component of your system

Comment: But when QueueBackgroundWorkItem used, ASP.NET tracks these items and prevents IIS from abruptly terminating the worker process so i used it for that purpose. Also, if one of them fails with an exception other one must send, so what is your solution for it?

Comment: Task.WhenAll trigger all tasks at the same time, and do not stop other tasks if exception raised in one of tasks. So all tasks will be executed, even few of them failed. Regarding HostingEnvironment - you are right, by mistake, i thought that you call this method on ThreadPool

Comment: So, is it fine to call it with  HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem?

Comment: Yes, it is ok. i have updated my answer. But ensure that you await SendEmails inside of QueueBackgroundWorkItem. But there is completely different approach to sending emails. i will update my answer in few minutes

Comment: That is fine but making sure that emails are sent is not so much essential in my case so i do not prefer a queuing system.

Comment: So, how could we catch exceptions separately for each task while not causing any of them waiting for previous one too?

Comment: It depend on what you would like to do with exception, but there are at least 2 approaches. First one - to use ContinueWith, example task.ContinueWith(v=> {Logger.Exception(v.Exception);}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted). Second is to subscribe to TaskScheduler event, example TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (sender, args) => { Logger.Exception(args.Exception);}